# Bash script to read from /dev/urandom

Tags: bash, shell, random, stdout

I want to make bash script that sends to stdout a file image containing only ASCII writable characters. My script should receive and accept only one argument containing the number of octets that should be read from `/dev/urandom`.

So, I need to read a given number of octets from `/dev/urandom` to create a file image to send to stdout.

I have this:

```sh
!/usr/bin/env bash

X=1

if [ $X -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: An argument is needed"
else
    strings /dev/urandom    
    echo the result
fi
```

I'm checking if there's any argument and, if there is, read the `/dev/urandom`. Of course this is just a sketch.

I was told there is a command called strings that reads and extracts sequences of characters from any file, but I've checked on the internet and I can't find much info about it.

So my question is: How do I read the number of octets given in the arguments from /dev/random so that I can put them in stdout (I know how to put on stdout :) )

Comment: interesting idea about wholesale creation of random chars. Not sure (and can't test right) if bash has same variable as ksh, $RANDOM. Here's an alternate solution that should be easier to manage, as you can assign one at a time, i.e. `myRand=$RANDOM; case $myRand in [A-Za-z0-9] * ) word=$word${myRand} ;((wordSize++));; esac` or similar. You'll need to wrap this in a while loop that monitors wordSize against your input `X`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks a lot, will test it right now :D

Comment: hm.. was just waking up when I answered above. Now I've noticed that myRand will be a number, not a char, you need to 'cast' the integer to a character. For some reason my printf builtin isn't working as expected, so best I can do is call an external program like awk like `myChar=$(awk -v num=$myRand 'END{printf("%c", num)}')`, and the use myChar, instead of myRand. Solution below looks good too, depending on your need, or who will maintain your code going forward. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strings` is not what you want.  If you just want random characters restricted to a particular set, filter out what you do not want.  To get $num alphanumeric chars from `/dev/urandom`, you can  do:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | dd bs=$num count=1 2> /dev/null
```

or

```
tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom ...
```

Note that this is not strictly portable.  Although the standard for `tr` states that it should work on any input file, my version is throwing the error 'Illegal byte sequence'.  Another option is:

```
perl -pe 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' /dev/urandom | dd bs=$num count=1 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: @chepner That's a good thought.  I've tried clearing LC_LOCALE and using a few different values, all with the same error.  Suggestions on a setting to use would be welcome!  (The error is occurring with BSD tr on OSX)

Comment: I managed to get it to work with `LANG=C tr ...`. Locale handling is a bit of a mystery to me as well, so I'm not sure if there is a more "correct" way to handle it.

Comment: @William Pursell Concerning the first idea:tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | dd bs=$num count=1 2> /dev/null What is the purpose of count=1 2> /dev/null? Sorry if it's a dumb question but I'm very new to this :) And thanks for the answer

Comment: `dd` has an unfortunate api.  It spews statistics about how much data it has copied to stderr and the `2> /dev/null` is to suppress that.  `count=1` is required to prevent `dd` from copying as much data as it can, which in this case would cause it to run forever (or until something external causes it to terminate, like a power failure or a signal.)

Comment: @William Pursell Thanks, now I get it :) Will test it right now

Comment: this didn't work with termux. instead, i used `shuf -i 0-100 -n 1 --random-source=/dev/urandom`